# What is the fastest way to subtract an ASCII value from a big number of characters

Tags: c#, string, csv, char, ascii

Basically I have an encrypted .csv file with a bunch of data from multiple machines. The encryption is really simple, every character's ASCII value is added 128 and the file extension is changed from .csv to .dlg. My question is: How to turn this file back to a normal .csv file? Here is what I've already tried:

```
string str1 = File.ReadAllText(@"C:\0328.dlg", Encoding.Default);
string str2 = "";
for (int i = 0; i <= 100000; i++)
{
    str2 += (char)(str1[i] - (char)128);
}
```

The main problem is that the file is really big, it contains around 13 million characters. The solution above "works", but it would probably take around 20 minutes to completely decrypt the file, while I want to do it in a few seconds. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: This is a terrible way to do it. You reallocate the string for each character added. Use a StringBuilder, or a plain array of characters. Note also that subtracting 128 is the same as clearing the most significant bit of a byte.

Comment: @500-InternalServerError Thank you for the feedback! I will try to utilize this information and let you know if it works.

Comment: 128 is 0x80.  So just or each character with 0x80.  I would cast to (byte) not char.  A char is two bytes. str2 |= (char)((byte)str1[i]);  What also may be fast is string str2 = str1.Select(x => (byte)x | 0x80).ToString();

Comment: @jdweng: OP wants to decrypt - so either AND with 0x7F or XOR with 0x80

Comment: I would use a streamreader to reduce memory size of creating two big strings.  Then read one byte at a time.

Comment: I don't see the point of doing such an unsafe encryption, but if you still want to do it, using XOR would be safer, because it would work with character codes >= 128. Also, it allows you to take a less obvious value like `'a' ^ 0x3a`. The same operation works for encryption and decryption.

Comment: @500-InternalServerError Using a StringBuilder instead of a string improved the performance massively. The whole file takes around a second to decrypt.

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes I do not make or encrypt the files, I just use the data from them. And the encryption is only there so that the users of the software don't go poking around the .csv files and mess them up and instead have to use the program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give LINQ a try:

```cs
string str2 = new string(str1.Select(c => (char)(c - 128)).ToArray());
```

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest this solution:

```cs
using (var source = new FileStream("some.dlg", FileMode.Open)){
    using (var target = new FileStream("some.csv", FileMode.Create))
    {
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        byte mask = 0x80;

        while(true) 
        {
            var count = await source.ReadAsync(buffer, 0, 1024);

            if (count == 0)
                break;

            for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) 
                buffer[i] = (byte)(buffer[i] ^ mask);

            await target.WriteAsync(buffer, 0, count);
        }
    }
}
```

The use of the `FileStream` lets you use your memory more efficent as to just read the whole file at once.